# Does this integral equation have a name, and is there a reference that deals with it?

Tags: reference-request, integral-equations

The equation is

$$S(z,t)=\int_a^b \int_c^d f(z,u) g(t,s) S(u,s) \, du \, ds$$

where $S$ is the unknown function and $f,\ g$ are fixed from the outset.

I can approximate solutions in some special cases with numerical methods but I'm interested in knowing if there's literature on this equation I could look to for more information.